# Переопределить класс?

Tags: php, ооп

У меня такая проблема. Есть класс, при его наследовании я добавляю в дочерний класс 
переменную, но при обращении к этой переменной ошибка.

```
class Player
{

}
class PePlayer extends Player
{
    public $message = "lol";
}

$player->message;
```

Пробовал так:

```
(PePlayer)$player->messsage;
```

Не помогло.

Comment: И не поможет. Родительские классы никогда не знают что появилось в дочерних. Также - может вы забыли echo?

Comment: А почему вы сразу не создаете дочерний класс (`new PePlayer`)? Чем обусловлено?

Comment: но в языках C# например есть as. $player as PePlayer

Comment: Обусловлено тем, что я работаю с левым софтом. Просто пример навел.

Comment: Только магия поможет.

Comment: @KirillMeøw `в языках C# например есть as. $player as PePlayer` - приведение к типу это одно. А работа с классом и потомком все равно неизменно и в том же C# та же конструкция не сработает. `Обусловлено тем, что я работаю с левым софтом. Просто пример навел` - ну пример такой же левый. Нужно понимать, что подразумевается под "левым софтом" и всё же чего вы хотите достичь

Answer (score 1):

Хммм... может вы забыли создать экземпляр класса?

```
class Player
{

}
class PePlayer extends Player
{
    public $message = "lol";
}
$player = new PePlayer();
echo $player->message;
//lol
```